# Alamofire request Cannot bypass ATS

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using xcode 8.1 and Alamofire 4.0.1

I am trying to send a request to a server. The server has a self-signed SSL certificate. The following code is what I am having now:

```
let manager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "someendpoint:1081": .disableEvaluation
    ]

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

    return Alamofire.SessionManager(
        configuration: configuration,
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
    )
}()

manager.request(endpoint, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON
```

Firstly I run into an error with error message of:

> An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.

I then override the ATS policy to allow arbitrary loads by adding the following to the plist file (I know it's dangerous, I am using it as a temp solution)

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

After I added the plist entry, it now prompts me with the error of:

> The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “somenedpoint” which could put your confidential information at risk.

Please note: **I do not own the server so everything has to be done on the client end.**

I have trying to debug this problem for 2 days but no luck. Could anyone please help to point our the problem?

Comment: omit the port from the server trust policy - just "someendpoint"  not "someendpoint:1081"